# Mongoose: Generate Schema from existing data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example, I have `user` collection in db:

```
{'_id':0, 'name': 'Joe', 'score':[80, 33]}
{'_id':1, 'name': 'Moe', 'score':[90, 81]}
... ...
```

How can I read this data with existing format, which means, use it's existing schema **without create a new one**.

I read Mongoose doc and googled for a while but didn't find satisfied answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work if you make a model with the same schema.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', score: [] });
var user = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Edit:

Mongoose is an ODM, so you need a schema to create objects. If you need to run queries and get raw data from the database, I would stick with this library:

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Comment: My question is, how to do it without create one. What if the collection is very complicated.

Comment: Without using models? it's already in json data, what do you mean by "read"

Comment: Mongoose is an ODM, if you need to run queries without schema relations, I would just not use mongoose and stick with mongodb lib.

Comment: I mean is there a way to read the data that already exists and then generate a schema from that existing data's schema.

Comment: Got it. This is more like `mongodb` lib's work rather than mongoose's, Thank you.

Comment: @wilbeibi  can we use aggregations using mongodb lib?

Answer (score 8):

When using mongoose with an existing collection, you have to reference the collection in your mongoose schema. The way to do this is to add the name of the collection to your schema. So if your collection is in 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test' and called 'things', you would use:

```
~~~
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ThingSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  }
});

const Model = mongoose.model('Thing', ThingSchema, 'things');
module.exports = Model;
~~~
```

Thanks to http://chrisflx.blogspot.fr/2014/04/nodejs-mongoose-with-preexisting-data.html?m=1